# Bash script to bring up and down an interface on loop

Tags: bash, shell, unix, networking, scripting

I use Ubuntu server as NAT router. WAN interface is `eth1` and LAN interface is `eth0`. I use ucarp virtual ip on LAN side for failover. I am writing a script which will bring down LAN interface `eth0` if WAN link or default gateway goes down (If LAN interface goes down, then ucarp can release the NAT gateway ip to another router on the network). Also if the WAN ip gets pinged then LAN interface should come up and should remain up until WAN ip can be pinged.

**Bash Script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
t1=$(ifconfig | grep -o eth0)
t2="eth0"
#RMT_IP = "8.8.8.8"
SLEEP_TIME="10"

ping -c 2 8.8.8.8 > /dev/null
   PING_1=$?

if [ $PING_1 = 1 ]; then
    if [ "$t1" != "$t2" ]; then
        ifconfig eth0 up
        echo "Iface brought up"
    else
        echo "Iface is already up"
    fi
else
    if [ "$t1" = "$t2" ]; then
        ifconfig eth0 down
        echo "Iface brought down"
    else
        echo "iface already down"
    fi
fi

sleep $SLEEP_TIME
```

The script does not work for me. What I want is, if a WAN ip can be pinged then the LAN interface `eth0` should remain up. If the WAN ip cannot be pinged, then the interface should be brought down. The script should run on loop every 10 seconds. If the WAN ip cannot be pinged for extended period of time then `eth0` should remain down only and if the WAN ip gets pinged after some time then `eth0` should be brought up. I also plan to run the script on boot up as an upstart job.

**EDIT 1:** 
My final script:

```
#!/bin/bash

timeout=5         # delay between checks
pingip='8.8.8.8'   # what to ping
iface="eth0"
LOG_FILE="/var/log/syslog"
isdown=0            # indicate whether the interface is up or down
                   # start assuming interface is up

while true; do
    LOG_TIME=`date +%b' '%d' '%T`
    if ping -q -c 2 "$pingip" >> /dev/null ; then      # ping is good - bring iface up
        if [ "$isdown" -ne 0 ] ; then
            ifup $iface && isdown=0
            printf "$LOG_TIME $0: Interface brought up: %s\n" "$iface" | tee -a $LOG_FILE
        fi
    else                                 # ping is bad - bring iface down
        beep -f 4000
        if [ "$isdown" -ne 1 ] ;  then
            ifdown $iface && isdown=1
            printf "$LOG_TIME $0: Interface brought down: %s\n" "$iface" | tee -a $LOG_FILE
        fi
    fi
    sleep "$timeout"
done
```

Comment: you can use `logger` to log to syslog, like `logger -t ifup "bringing iface $iface up"` which will automatically convert the message to the syslog format. You should also quote your vars (`iface` `LOG_FILE`) and dont use variables inside `printf` strings, use them as parameteres, like `printf "time is %s\n" "$time"`. Also, capital variables are by convension used by the environment, you should use lower case ones. Lastly, this should work fine with `sh`, you don't need `#!/bin/bash`, just `#!/bin/sh`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this one
if ping succeeds then bring `$iface` up
if ping fails then bring `$iface` down

```
#!/bin/bash

timeout=3               # delay between checks
iface="eth0"            # which interface to bring up/down
pingip='8.8.8.8'        # what to ping
isdown=-1               # indicate whether the interface is up(0) or down(1)
                        # start in unknown state

while true; do
    if ping -q -c 2 "$pingip"; then       # if ping is succeeds bring iface up
        if [ "$isdown" -ne 0 ]; then      # if not already up
            ifconfig "$iface" up && isdown=0
            printf ":: iface brought up: %s\n" "$iface"
        fi
    elif [ "$isdown" -ne 1 ]; then        # if ping failed, bring iface down, if not already down
        ifconfig "$iface" down && isdown=1
        printf ":: iface brought down: %s\n" "$iface"
    fi
    sleep "$timeout"
done
```

Comment: If the interface is already up, and after 10 seconds the scripts again executes the code to bring up the interface, then wouldn't that affect the performance? But if the same line is executed again again, it doesn't show an error though.

Comment: as I dont know of a direct way to check if the iface is up, to find out if it is, I'd have to use something like `ifconfig | grep eth0` which actually is much worse, cause 1. it calls ifconfig either way, 2. the pipe spawns a subshell, and that means the environment has to be loaded again, and 3. loads and executes grep, all that to decide if eth0 is up, and if not re-execut ifconfig to bring it up. So, no, I dont think it's worth it.

Comment: The command `ifconfig eth0 down` does not work. However `ifup` and `ifdown` commands work. But those commands can be run only once. Looping the same command shows error. So is there any way to set a variable when, lets say, `ifup eth0` is executed, and if the interface is already up ,the script will check the variable which was set and the same command won't be executed again.

Comment: alright, I introduced `isdown` var, that gets the value `1` (true) when the interface is down. so `ifconfig up` is executed only when `isdown` is set. `ifup` and `ifdown` are not standard. I dont have them in my system. Use them if you like, but dont expect your script to be working elsewhere then. Keep that in mind ;)

Comment: Would it execute `ifconfig down` also only once by looking up the variable which was set? According to some howtos `ifconfig down`  just flushes the interface, so the interface comes up on its own after few seconds. However, ifdown brings down the physical interface and flushes the ip as well.

Comment: done, will invoke `ifconfig down` (or `ifdown`) only if interface is not down already. by default it is assumed that the interface is down. to change that change the initial value of `isdown` on the top (and fix the comment appropriately)

Comment: Here is the modified and testing version of your script: http://pastebin.com/sJuNmLPU The script gives ``isdown not found`` error.

Comment: that's because of `#!/bin/sh` and not using a `bash` shebang, `((..))` is bash syntax. I will alter that, so that it's `sh/POSIX` compatible. Also some small fixtures ;)